# Using a range in GetChar in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, indexing

In other words, how can I index a string.

```
Dim foo as String = "Foobar"
GetChar(foo, 2+3)
```

Will return 'r', I however want it to return characters 2 through 3; 'ob'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
Dim s As String = foo.Substring(2, 2)
```